# What is this badge?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Look at this badge and please tell me what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the reward for being a beta tester of the game:

[image]

Source:  ["A Well-Deserved Reward" anouncement](https://worldoftanks.com/en/news/announcements/well-deserved-reward-1118/)